# Analysis of PIT file for Samsung Galaxy C7 (SM-C7000)

Tags: samsung, rom-flashing, partitions, stock-rom, formatting

I got a Samsung Galaxy C7 (SM-C7000) from China. I'm trying to install Hong Kong firmware on it and of course, got the partition size error in Odin. I searched around and found one `pit` file for my model Hong Kong. However, I'm concerned if it is the right file or not.

The content of the PIT file: https://pastebin.com/FncY05pg.

USERDATA view

[image]

Can I flash the attached `pit` file? Otherwise, what is the correct file for my phone's Hong Kong PIT file?

**My Phone**

- Model - SM-C7000
- Variant - China
- Storage - 32 GB

Answer (score 0):

From what I've been told, the PIT file for HK and China versions are the same.

https://www.sammobile.com/forum/showthread.php?t=35053&page=2 (dead link)

---

There is definitely something up with the PIT files. I also have the 32GB device. And the partition structure defined in all the PIT files is for the 64GB version. The only strange thing is that I'm able to flash the Chinese versions but not the HK even though they apparently have the same PIT. Both PIT from a CNC firmware I can flash without problem and PIT from HK version I cannot have the same file checksum: D178FC793FDC4B833BDFB4FD6176159A.

I noticed there is one big difference between the CNC and HK images. The AP file for HK includes a userdata partition inside but the CNC images do not. That is the difference and when it comes to writing that part it stops. Also, from what I've been reading out PIT files. Block Size is the point on the disk where the partition begins and Block Count is the actual size of the partition. In this PIT file, the userdata partition has a block count of 0 which seems odd. And would explain why the CNC image flashes and HK ones do not.

Answer (score 0):

I bought SM-C7000 and it was on TGY (HK) version with Play Store. I love to root my Android phones, found a post on XDA, and was able to root, install Xposed, etc. One night, I thought to remove the root because Xposed modules were not working well. So, I unrooted the device in SU. Restarted and then the accident happened. My device was bricked. I tried to install the HK version from Sammobile but in vain. Always got auth error or invalid data error showing data is too big. Then I tried Smart Switch and downloaded it by entering the model number and the serial number of my device. My phone booted. But when I used it, it was now the CHC (China) version with no Play Store. Then I again started searching. Again file big error. Searched the net and found that it was a partition error and I need a PIT file. But after searching, I found that the PIT file for both TGY (HK) and CHC (China) are the same.

For Odin, the solution is to first flash only the `ap` file and it will give the error at userdata ext 4. Remove mobile and again, put it into download mode, and now flash `bl`, `cp` and `csc` files only. Remember not to touch repartition. And untick reboot also. After flashing, reboot into recovery and wipe data and cache partition.

Now your phone will be the TGY (HK) version with Play Store, etc.